# How to get reference to an existing taskpane?

Tags: office365, office365-apps

I've seen tutorials about controlling custom task panes , but I still can't figure it out.
I've been developing in a different project a TASK-Pane (it has several classes, and script files) which I intend to control in a different project (I want to make it appear and disappear). How can I get this task-pane object without having to build this solution from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure that I understand the goals here. Also, if you can post links to the tutorials you are referencing, it may shed some light.

If you are attempting to make a task pane app show and hide from somewhere outside the app command that launches the task pane, I believe that is not possible.

Again, If you can share the scenario you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply @SharePointing! Here is the  [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608590.aspx) I've made.
I'd like to anchieve something similar to what this tutorial anchieves, but with a  task pane I had developed previously (an App with several folders and scripts ..) and not one I had to build everysingle component